# JAXB classes not generated for schemas on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jaxb

I am new to JAXB and am having trouble getting it to run on eclipse. I downloaded the jaxb plug in for eclipse. I now get a New JAXB Project Wizard, but no "generate jaxb classes" option when I right-click on an xsd or xml file. When I add an xml file in the instance folder, Castor runs automatically and classes get generated. But when I add an xsd file in the schema folder, Castor runs again, I get a "completed" message, but no classes are created in the jaxb folder. Where could I be going wrong?

I tried and get the same results on both Eclipse Europa and Indigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. I used Eclipse for Java EE. Now I get the Generate JAXB Classes option, and it works!